# Share a treestore for multiple treepanels

Tags: extjs, extjs4, treepanel

I have a following JSON reply from server:

```
{
    "stats": [
    {
        "text": "Home",
        "leaf": true,
        "dbName": "home"
    },
    {
        "text": "Sveatlo",
        "expanded": false,
        "leaf": false,
        "dbName": "sveatlo",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Vydané faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "vydane-faktury"
            },
            {
                "text": "Prijaté faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "prijate-faktury"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "Hájočka",
        "expanded": false,
        "leaf": false,
        "dbName": "hajocka",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Vydané faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "vydane-faktury"
            },
            {
                "text": "Prijaté faktúry",
                "leaf": true,
                "dbName": "prijate-faktury"
            }
        ]
    }
    ],
    "success": true,
    "contacts": [
    {
        "text": "Address book",
        "leaf": true,
        "dbName": "addressbook"
    },
    {
        "text": "Contacts",
        "leaf": true,
        "dbName": "contacts"
    }
    ]
}
```

And I have two treepanels "stats" and "contacts". I want to load content for both of them with one request. Currently my treepanels' definition look like this:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    title: 'Statistics',
    id: 'statsMenu',
    store: Ext.getStore('MenuStats').load({
        params: {
            auth: sessionStorage.authSessionId,
            hostname: sessionStorage.hostname
        }
    }),
    rootVisible: false,
}{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    title: 'Contacts',
    id: 'contactsMenu',
    store: Ext.getStore('MenuContacts'),
    rootVisible: false,
}]
```

But I want the 2nd treepanel ("Contacts") to use the same treestore just with another root.
Is there any way to manage this?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: After reading your code in depth again, I realize that my answer is not correct. 
It isn't possible to load data in two stores with one request, and with the given json structure, I don't think it is possible to load all in one store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again, guess I'll need to rebuild it.